How to retrieve HTTP request post form data from QHttpServerRequest on the server side
I have a website that posts an html form with a file upload. It looks like this:
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/node/x/update-firmware">
    <input type="file" id="firmwarefile" name="firmwarefile" />

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Update firmware">
</form

Now on a Qt server I want to process this form and get the data from the QHttpServerRequest. So that would be in a function that looks like this:
server.route("/node/x/update-firmware/", QHttpServerRequest::Method::Post, [] (const QHttpServerRequest &request) {
    // This prints the entire body as a string
    qDebug() << "QHttpServerRequest" << request.body();
 
    // Redirect to status page
    QHttpServerResponse response(QHttpServerResponse::StatusCode::SeeOther);
    response.setHeader("Location", "/status");

    return response;
    });

Now I can see that the data comes in when I look at the request.body(). And I could probably come up with a function to process that string to retrieve the posted data. However I'm hoping that there is an easier way like in PHP where you can easily use the global $_POST with the array of posted form data.
Is anyone aware of how to get the content of the form in Qt? Any help is much appreciated.
